# How to rename object data response in React

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to rename an object property for an array of objects.

Here is generally what the response looks like:

```
response: [{
   name: 'Manage User',
   id: 1,
}, {
   name: 'Manage Region',
   id: 2,
}, {
   name: 'Manage BTP',
   id: 3,
}],
```

**the function**

```
getResponseRename() {          
  return this.response.map((data) =>
    <div>
        <p>title: {data.key}</p>
        <span>key: {data.title}</span>
        <hr/>
    </div>
  );
}

render() {
 return(
    <div>{this.getResponseRename()}</div>
 )
}
```

and I would like to change the payload `name` to `title` and `id` to `key`.

How could I change this and mapping the new response data after rename it? any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to just display `name` and `id` as `title` and `key` in the render method, or do you want to change your actual data to those values?

Comment: yeah I want to change the actual data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this with ES6 destructuring aliases:

```
getResponseRename() {
  return this.response.map(({id: key, name: title}) =>
    <div>
      <p>title: {key}</p>
      <span>key: {title}</span>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will destructure your callback parameter into the `id` and `name` variables, and assign them a new variable name (aka an alias).

---

From the [**MDN** documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

> A property can be unpacked from an object and assigned to a variable with a different name than the object property.
>
> ```
> var o = {p: 42, q: true};
> var {p: foo, q: bar} = o;
>
> console.log(foo); // 42 
> console.log(bar); // true
> ```

Answer (score 2):

get your data:

```
response: [{
  name: 'Manage User',
  id: 1,
}, {
  name: 'Manage Region',
  id: 2,
}, {
  name: 'Manage BTP',
  id: 3,
}],
```

reformat it:

```
const reformattedData = response.map((data) => {
  return {
    title: data.name,
    key: data.id,
  };
})
```

use it!

```
getResponseRename() {

  return reformattedData.map((data) =>
      <div>
          <p>title: {data.key}</p>
          <span>key: {data.title}</span>
          <hr/>
      </div>
  );
}
```